# Java URL constructor allows spaces

Tags: java

I'm confused with why this is valid and not throwing an exception:

```
final URL u = new URL("https:// google . c o m foo bar")
```

Isn't this an invalid URL?

Comment: I'd check the docs. It's possible it URL encodes anything you put in the constructor, which would replace the space with %20.

Comment: `u.toURI()` throws an exception, but the constructor does not.

Comment: @Kousha It does, but only "if no protocol is specified, or an unknown protocol is found, or spec is null".  "https://" is a valid protocol specification, and " google . c o m foo bar" isn't `null`, so...  It seems a weird decision to only enforce strict parsing according to RFC2396 in toURI(), though.

Comment: URL constructor does not do strict validation of the URL path. If want URL encoded use URLEncoder.encode() which would return "https%3A%2F%2F+google+.+c+o+m+foo+bar" for the input above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  java.net.URL is a very old class which was part of Java 1.0.  It does little to no checking of the syntax of its String argument.

Later, the [java.net.URI](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URI.html) class was added, which does all of the proper checks.  And a valid URI can be converted to a URL with the [toURL()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URI.html#toURL%28%29) method.